# AVPlayerLayer Popgesture Glitch

Tags: ios, swift, animation, avplayerlayer

EDIT: https://bitbucket.org/KevinvandenhoekBeast/avplayerlayerpopgesture/overview <-- A simple sample project that recreates the problem, click on the video to push the detailviewcontroller, then popgesture back. The animations happen in the NavigationAnimator, and the popgesture logic is in the NavigationInteractor. The NavigationTransitioningView protocol defines the methods that are used by the animator to transition the video from one frame to the other.

Hello fellow developers,

For the past few evenings I’ve been struggling with a persistent and 100% reproducable animation glitch. I’ve been working on an app that has custom navigation transition animations that work both ways (push and pop). The transition I made is having a UIView type object moving in the transitioncontext from 1 view to the other, and so far it’s been working wonderfully using a protocol that I made for the two involved viewcontrollers, which lets them tell the animator what view they want to transition, and their respective from and to frames.

I use this on images, and on videoplayers, IE when the user clicks on an image in a collectionView the image frame animates from its origin in the original viewcontroller towards the position it should take in the detailViewController. The same happens for playing videoplayers. It works perfectly when I simply push a viewcontroller, and pop, for both videoplayers and images. However, recently I implemented a custom pop gesture (with a UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition subclassing class). The popgesture seemed to work wonderfully and I was looking at some beautifully lerped animation states, until I tried it with a videoplayer and the horror started.

When doing the popgesture with a videoplayer that is animated from one frame to another (as in CGRect) there is some extremely glitchy behaviour. The popgesture pretty much consistently cancels after a (very) short amount of time, generally at about 0.1 ish progress (an interesting detail: if I swipe very quick the gesture is completed and nothing bugs/glitches), but despite cancelling, the pop does (seem to) happen and I land back at the previous viewcontroller. This is where things get really funky. The visibility / frame of the viewcontroller is changed somewhat, like there is some clipping (somewhere past halfway the view cuts off), and the entire view seems to be shifted (upwards in my case), and generally repeating the popgesture worsens things. However, tapping on the view still responds as if the view is in its normal position (without the shift upwards). This leads me to believe this is some sort of a layer glitch with some of the stuff happening when animating an AVPlayerLayer with a UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.

When I don't update the playerlayer containing view it’s frame while animating, the bug doesn’t occur. Similarly, when I remove the player’s layerClass override, and simply add an AVPlayerLayer as a sublayer (and update it’s frame in the layoutSubviews call), I also don’t experience the bug, but I get the side effect that the playerlayer immediately jumps to it’s final frame, despite the containing view animating properly).

I’m sincerely hoping there is someone that has a deeper knowledge in CALayers, and maybe recognizes these symptoms and could hopefully point me to what’s really causing them. Many thanks in advance.

I useful, I’m willing to upload a video of the issue.

tl;dr using a custom UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition subclass to lerp the frame property of a view with a layerClass of AVPlayerLayer from 1 CGRect to another causes very strange things to happen in the destination viewcontroller (its root view visually shifting / changing frame / clipping, while the touch area is as if the view isnt shifted (IE tapping a collectionViewCell highlights / selects the cell above)), despite the exact same animation logic working flawlessly when used without the UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition subclass popgesture handling.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It's great that you're willing to upload a video/gif of the issue.  More important is the code relevant to the error you're seeing.  Specifically, the example code you provide should be minimal, verifiable, and complete, so that others can try to reproduce the issue locally.  See here for more info- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks! Tomorrow Ill make a simple reproduction app that focuses only on this issue, in the meanwhile, if this issue rings a bell for anyone I’d be glad to hear :)

Comment: Alright, I created a 'simple' source App, that solely focuses on doing this transitioning task, which has the exact same symptoms as the project im working with. I posted it on bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/KevinvandenhoekBeast/avplayerlayerpopgesture/overview

If you run it, and click on the video, it should transition to a detail page, with the video animating to the new target frame. I made the target frames have corner lines to clarify the target positions. Now, when you try to go from the detailviewcontroller back to the previous viewcontroller with a popgesture the glitch will occur